# System tray icons too big

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, notification-area

I recently changed my computer, I have now a laptop "Dell Inspiron 13 5378 2-in-1", and in this computer, with Windows 10, the icons in system tray are too big, more especifically, they have more space around the icon.

I have to say that I have the taskbar on the left of the screen, so if I unlock it and try to minimize it, the icons are placed one on top of the other, like they were in line, instead of to be in pairs. I attached a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try going to "Display settings" > "Change the size of text, apps and other items: xxx%"? It might be set to 150%, change it 125% and restart the machine. It should help. Strangely enough, changing back to 150% keeps the notification icons small (i.e. they can be displayed in pairs). Looks like a bug.

Comment: @adgu - Thank you! This worked for me - I had icons in a grid, but enormously spaced out. Switching the scaling up and back down to 100% fixed it. Would upvote if I could, this should be an answer.

Comment: @adgu yes, I tried and it didn't work. The problem should be related to my 2-in-1 laptop, it's like the system tray icon is displayed in tablet mode even when I disabled it.

Comment: I get this problem from having a 4K TV hooked up to my computer. I like to use my computer from the couch occasionally so I have the TV set to 300% scaling. When I Win + P back to only display on my main computer monitor, it seems the system tray icons inherit the 300% scaling even though that monitor is no longer in use. I don't even have my system tray on that monitor so I'm not sure where the problem is coming from exactly.

Comment: I had the same issue, and suspect it's because my new laptop has a touch screen, and Windows try to space buttons enough to be able to reliably touch-click them.

Comment: @Jeroen could you try the answer I just posted?

Comment: Alas, I cannot. The laptop I had this one had hardware problems so I'm not using it anymore at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

It hasn't happened to me in a while, but what I usually do to fix it is the following:

1. Navigate to the following key in the Registry Editor: `...\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell`
2. Set the `TabletMode` value to `1`, even if it is already set to `0`, which is the correct value.
3. Log out or reboot the PC
4. Set the `TabletMode` value to `0` again
5. Log out or reboot the PC

These steps usually solve the problem for me.

Can you try and see if this solves it for you?